# applescript: avoid sound when using Finder to move files

Tags: audio, applescript, move

I am trying to process a number of files in Applescript. This includes moving
each file to a work directory for processing

When my script executes

```
tell application "Finder"
    move  file to workdir
end tell
```

It always causes a sound (just like moving a file using the finder GUI dos)
How can I prevent this? The script will likely run for many hours and constant dinging from this script would be disturbing. I cannot turn sound off completely as other things may need to alert me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you explicitly stated *"I cannot turn sound off completely as other things may need to alert me"* in your OP, I'd suggest you use the `move` *command* from **System Events's Disk-Folder-File Suite**, as it does not make any sound using this method.

> **move** *v* : Move disk item(s) to a new location.
>         **move** disk item : The disk item(s) to be moved.
>               to location specifier : The new location for the disk item(s).
>               → disk item

**Example:**

```
set thisItem to "/path/to/disk item"
set thisFolder to "/path/to/folder"

tell application "System Events"
    move disk item thisItem to thisFolder
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the sound through a system file named "Volume Mount.aif". A non-destructive way to do this is to move the file to another location. Root permissions are needed to move the file.

To execute this command you will also need to disable system integrity protection:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

You can move it by typing the following command into terminal:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/Volume\ Mount.aif ~/Desktop/
```

To move it back:

```
sudo mv ~/Desktop/Volume\ Mount.aif /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/
```

A restart is required for the sound to work again.

Comment: The OP clearly stated _"I cannot turn sound off completely as other things may need to alert me"_ and considering System Events provides a way to do it without making any sound, there is absolutely no need to go thru such rigmarole.

Comment: It's only disabling the 1 sound, not disabling sound completely. I only listed it as an alternative, as OP could prefer not to have this sound when using finder, rather than only when script runs.

Comment: For the record, I didn't down-vote your answer however I think you're really missing the point! To be blunt, what you're suggesting as an alternative is ludicrous, especially in light of the fact that there was already an appropriate answer to the question that stayed within the context of AppleScript. The file you're talking about moving is a System file and used for more then the sound made when moving a file in Finder. Also the OP mentioned it being a long running process, so he/she may do other things in Finder while that script is running, so why cripple the system!

Comment: It's not my intention to cripple anyone's system. Some people dislike the sound and never want to hear it. If I was one of them, I would probably disable it, but I accept your point about the applescript context. Should probably delete this answer then.